# How to efficiently use child_added

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am very familiar with the concept of "child_added", "child_changed", "child_removed" and "value". 
Whenever I use a list, that is supposed to dynamically update itself, I am supposed to use all the functions except "value" and whenever I just need a static snapshot of data, I will use "value".

My question is as follows:

Is it really the best way to write three triggers (four if you count "child_moved") whenever I have a list? A simple app has a lot of lists.
If yes, how is it done in the most efficient way in javascript? My current approach is as follows:

- on child_added: Iterate over my entire list; look where the key is equal to the key I just received from the event and save it's value as oldValue; now find the index of prevChildKey and insert the just received child after the index of prevChildKey while removing myList[myList.indexOf(oldValue)] from the list
- on child_changed: Iterate over my entire list; look where the key is equal to the key I just received from the event and save it's value as oldValue; set myList[myList.indexOf(oldValue)] = newValue;
- on child_removed: same as above, just with myList.splice(...)
- on child_moved: I havn't implemented this. But I will probably need it, when child_changed was called and this resulted in the ordering of my elements changing. So there is a very similar logic to child_added

Is there a way to handle this in a more elegant way? I first tried just accessing the element by myList[child.key], but this doesn't work for me.

**Edit:** Added code to demonstrate it, a lot of code to apply for every list in my application

```
myRef.orderByChild("timestamp").on("child_added",(message,prevChildKey) => {
        //Transform the firebase-date into my own format
        var template = {
          senderName: message.val().sender,
          time:  message.val().timestamp,
          id: message.key}

        //Check where to add this
        if(prevChildKey){
            this.messages.forEach(currentMessage => {
                if(currentMessage.id === prevChildKey){
                    var indexToAdd = this.messages.indexOf(currentMessage);
                    this.messages.splice(indexToAdd+1,0,template];
                }
            });
        }else
            this.messages.unshift(template);

});
myRef.on("child_changed", message => { //orderByChild makes no sense here, right ?
    //Transform the firebase-date into my own format
    var template = {
        senderName: message.val().sender,
        time:  message.val().timestamp,
        id: message.key}

    var toBeUpdated = undefined;
    this.messages.forEach(currentMessage => {
        if(currentMessage.id === message.id){
            this.messages[this.messages.indexOf(currentMessage)] = template;
        }
    })

    //How do I preserve ordering here, since I was ordering by timestamp on child_added before and I don't check if that value changed
}
myRef.on("child_removed", oldMessage => {

    //Remove the message
    this.messages.forEach(currentMessage => {
        if(currentMessage.id === oldMessage.id){
            this.messages.splice(this.messages.indexOf(currentMessage),1);
        }
    })
}
myRef.orderByChild("timestamp").on("child_moved", (message,prevChildKey) => { //Not too sure, how this works. Do I need the orderByChild here to preserve it ?

    var messageToMove = undefined;
    var messagePosition = undefined;
    var indexToMoveTo = undefined;
    this.messages.forEach(currentMessage => {
        if(currentMessage.id === message.id){
            messagePosition = this.messages.indexOf(currentMessage);
            messageToMove = this.messages[messagePosition];
        }
        if(currentMessage.id === prevChildKey){
            indexToMoveTo = this.messages.indexOf(currentMessage) + 1;
        }
    })

    //Remove the message from where it was
    this.messaged.splice(messagePosition,1);
    //Add the message at the new position
    this.messages.splice(indexToMoveTo,0,messageToMove);

}
```

Comment: You're asking us if there is a more efficient way to do something. Most of us are not good at parsing a description of code. So please post the [minimal actual code that demonstrates your current solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll probably be able to help more.

Comment: I added some code as demonstration

Comment: The use case description is a bit unclear; *why* are you iterating over a list to see if the key is the same as the key you just received? Are you trying to keep posts ordered? If so, just timestamp each post and they will always be in the correct order? Also, if a post is added, changed or removed that specific post is passed to your app providing direct access to that node so again, no need to iterate over the list to find it. i.e. If node_3 is changed, that key (node_3) is passed to your app and you can directly access node_3/child_nodes to  update them.

Comment: If the timestamp changes for example, I need to reorder them. Yes I want a dynamic list of messages. How can I directly access node_3 in my array? I know that i receive the node as the parameter but I need to find the old version of said node and I can only do that by finding the index of the element with the same id (key). Or am I missunderstanding something there ? Since I added it with child_added I need to update it on child_changed.

Comment: Whether implementing `child_*` events is better than `value` really depends on your use-case. On the wire-level they are exactly the same, and they're purely a client-side detail. In general `child_*` events make it easier to granularly update their corresponding UI elements, since they often map directly to DOM updates. But a framework like React changes that again, since it does efficient delta detection itself. There are nearly as many options/considerations as there are projects to use Firebase on, so it's hard to pick a single "best" approach. What's your specific concern with your code?

Comment: Well with the current version, the problem is that I am loading everything in my list whenever anything changes. So in this case, I was loading all the messages if a single message changed (I adopted the child_added version here since this seems important). But I also show friendlists, where I load the entire list, also containing profile images whenever anything in the list changes. I guess this is costly.
Using the approach "child_added" seems like a lot of code to implement for every of my list and I was hoping there is some "easier" way in JS to do this. I am using Ionic 3 if that helps.

Comment: The important point here is when using child_* events, your app is passed the single item that changed as a snapshot. They snapshot will have a key and from there you have direct access to that nodes children, eliminating the need to iterate over, or use a .value event (which as you know loads *everything*). Adding child_* observers is very little code and is really the way to go per what @FrankvanPuffelen stated. Also, in your question you mentioned 'lots of lists' and it's unclear what that means - 10? 10000? Why so many? We may be able to help more if the question is clarified.

Comment: Well I am iterating over my local list, the one that is being displayed in the *ngFor to find the value to replace. I know that I can - for example - just receive message172D2E and know that just that one changed. But I need to find said message172D2E in my local list to update (for example) the timestamp. This is what bothers me. Like I said, maybe I am missunderstanding something but I can't just push the node I just got, since it would be within my list two times then. So I need to delete the old version (which I can find by the id - it obviously stays the same)

Comment: Any by "lots of lists" I mean an arbitrary number. I currently have about 10 lists (e.g. friendlist, chat-messages, friend-requests, ....). But that number may grow as the application progresses.

Comment: There's a disconnect here somewhere. When say 'find said message172D2E in my local list to update the timestamp' what defines a 'local list'? You would also not need to push the node you just got because it would have already been updated which is what caused the child_changed event to fire in the first place. The whole concept of Firebase is that when you write a change to a node, all of the clients listing on that node will be notified of that change and can take appropriate action (update UI, notify user, whatever).

Comment: By "local list" I mean the array that is being shown in my .html file to display the containing information. More precisely the "friends" in *ngFor="let friend of friends". In said friends array, I store all the informations that I receive by the on("child_*") events. And to update the {{friend.timestamp}} value in my view, I need to update the corresponding  element within the "friends" array. So I somehow need to map the element I get from firebase to my local representation of it. This is what is shown in the code-section of my original post (in that case it's messages and not friends)

Answer (score 0):

> So I somehow need to map the element I get from firebase to my local
>   representation of it.

Oh! That's easy!

As you are aware, Firebase stores it's data in key: value pairs.

So for example a users node would be

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Bill" 
   uid_1
      name: "Larry"
```

If you were to change the name in a node, say Bill to Billy, the uid_0 node (and child data) is passed to your app in a snapshot, with the key being uid_0. That key would correspond to the data you have stored in your array.

There's a multitude of ways to go about this.

One way is to store objects in your array as dictionaries of key value pairs. Some pseudo code..

```
myDictionary = [ "uid_0": [name: "Billy"] ]
myArray[0] = myDictionary
```

However, a 'classier' way to do it would be to create a user class and store those in the array, with the key (uid_0) as one of the properties of the class

```
UserClass {
   key = ""
   name = ""
}

let aUser = UserClass
aUser.key = snapshot.key
aUser.name = snapshot.value("name") //loose pseudo code, dont copy/paste!

myArray[0] = userClass
```

Then when your app receives a snapshot, you can query the array for the userClass.key received from the snapshot.key

The big picture is that everything is Firebase is stored and accessed via a key, it remains consistent and unchanging so it's the tool to use to keep your friends (messages) array sync'd with Firebase.

Edit: you could implement a linked list if you want direct access to the sorted array objects by storing the keys and element numbers in a HashMap (dictionary).

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("uid_0", "0");
```

then to print out the index for uid_0

```
System.out.println(map.get("uid_0"));
```

which outputs the index: 0

If you just want to use one storage mechanism, a TreeMap (natural order) or a LinkedHashMap is the way to go.

```
map.put("uid_0", *values for uid_0, name etc*);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but to find the corresponding userClass.key for the snapshot.key I will still need to iterate over my array to find it. Don't I ? This is my current approach, just without the class. Always finding the matching userClass.key and keeping the ordering is still a lot of code (as shown in my post).

Comment: My apologies - I was speaking at a high level to provide background on leveraging the snapshot.key to keep things lined up. I updated the answer with more details - I would suggest leveraging a LinkedHashMap for storage as your data is probably ordered by Firebase when reading it in and the LinkedHashMap would maintain that order and give the ability to directly access the snapshot.key elements.

Comment: I was considering this too. But first off, as far as I know, javascript doesn't support LinkedHasMaps. Only directories, which don't keep the order. Another point is, that within the view *ngFor (for Angular) can't iterate over Maps. So I need to write a seperate function, providing the keys as an array and then reference to the exact entry within my directory by the key. The sad thing is, all the tutorials I find online just ignore child_* (except child_added) events for simplicity. But there must be a smooth way to solve this in javascript (or typescript).

Comment: There are a couple of [external libraries](https://github.com/monmohan/dsjslib) that offer a solution, and I recall seeing a SortedMap library as well - google that.